# Move partitions mounted at /mnt to /media?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, nautilus

I've 4 Ext4 partitions on 2TB HDD mounted at `/mnt`. I wanted to mount them at `/media`.

my questions are

- How can I do that?
- After mounting at `/media` will they be visible in the sidebar in nautilus? (now they are not)
- what are the advantages or disadvantages of doing it for partitions that mostly contains Video/Music/images (i.e, Media)?

output of `cat /etc/fstab`

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name 
devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=6de91b2b-f519-445c-9b59-5b3f0ac727c5 /               ext4    
errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=bd7673b1-589a-4ab6-842c-0324d563c838 /home           ext4    
defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=d1749176-6c41-4961-a6bd-0c6a56968970 none            swap    sw              
0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/54c9765b-af6d-4a62-905f-09b56e280178 /mnt/Stuff auto 
nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/b2d7f1a7-f3e6-4ca5-9925-d8225c897e4d /mnt/Movies 
auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/c2104e2a-cc8e-4b7b-9bba-a05d316472b4 /mnt/Hollywood 
auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/707694b6-97b8-4374-9283-c98192591486 /mnt/Series 
auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

output of `lsblk`

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sdb      8:16   0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sdb4   8:20   0   713G  0 part /mnt/Series
├─sdb2   8:18   0   220G  0 part /mnt/Movies
├─sdb3   8:19   0   710G  0 part /mnt/Hollywood
└─sdb1   8:17   0   220G  0 part /mnt/Stuff
sda      8:0    0 111.8G  0 disk 
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  14.3G  0 part /
├─sda3   8:3    0  44.9G  0 part 
├─sda1   8:1    0   7.6G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda6   8:6    0  44.9G  0 part /home
```

[image]

Comment: [Partition does not show up after editing fstab](//askubuntu.com/a/798039) ?

Comment: @Zanna can i do that from the disks application?

Comment: What do you mean you have a 2 TB hard drive mounted at /mnt? I don't think you can mount a hard drive. You can only mount partitions.

Comment: @misha ive **4 ext4 partitions** that are made on **2TB HDD** which are **mounted at /mnt**

Comment: How can you have four working partitions mounted at the same directory? You can only have one working partition per directory, as far as I know. What does the `df -h -T` command show?

Comment: @misha the partitions, if there are 4, will be mounted `/mnt/Hollywood` `/mnt/Movies` `/mnt/Series` and `/mnt/Stuff` Or these could all be directories in one partition

Comment: And that's exactly what I'm talking about. You have four different directories for four partitions.

Comment: @Zanna yeah, you're right, those are my partitions, 4 of them, does my question have less information? should i update it with something?

Comment: @misha Yes and I want to move all of them to `/media` like `/media/sumeet/Hollywood` and `/media/sumeet/Stuff` and so on

Comment: Regarding whether you can do it using GNOME disks, yes you can use it to edit `fstab` for you, see for example [How to mount a new drive on startup](//askubuntu.com/a/588034). And yes you should edit your question to include the output of `cat /etc/fstab` and `lsblk` when the partitions are mounted, if you still need help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following command is used to unmount whatever is currently mounted at a particular directory (`-v` turns on verbose output so that you're informed by the command as to what's going on during the mounting/unmounting process):

```
sudo umount -v [DIRECTORY]
```

In your case, you're going to have to run these four commands:

```
sudo umount -v /mnt/Stuff
sudo umount -v /mnt/Movies
sudo umount -v /mnt/Hollywood
sudo umount -v /mnt/Series
```

Here's how you remount your partitions (and yes, your file manager will have no problems seeing and opening them up) (don't forget to create the directories themselves first: `sudo mkdir /media/Stuff` etc.):

```
sudo mount -t auto -o rw /dev/sdb1 /media/Stuff -v
sudo mount -t auto -o rw /dev/sdb2 /media/Movies -v
sudo mount -t auto -o rw /dev/sdb3 /media/Hollywood -v
sudo mount -t auto -o rw /dev/sdb4 /media/Series -v
```

Now, open the `/etc/fstab` file like this:

```
sudo nano -w /etc/fstab
```

And change all occurrences of `mnt` in there to `media`:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/54c9765b-af6d-4a62-905f-09b56e280178 /media/Stuff auto 
nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/b2d7f1a7-f3e6-4ca5-9925-d8225c897e4d /media/Movies 
auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/c2104e2a-cc8e-4b7b-9bba-a05d316472b4 /media/Hollywood
auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/707694b6-97b8-4374-9283-c98192591486 /media/Series 
auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

As for your last question, there are neither real advantages nor disadvantages to moving your partitions to the media directory except that the mnt directory traditionally has been used primarily for temporary mounting. So, it might indeed be logical to have your stuff mounted in the media directory, though the media directory is typically used for removable media such as USB sticks, external hard drives, CD-ROMs et cetera. Other than that, it makes no difference whatsoever where your things are mounted in the file system.

Comment: but they will be visible in left sidebar of Nautilus, right? that is still an advantage?

Comment: `mount: mount point /media/Stuff does not exist` do i need to create that folder in media?

Comment: Yes, you do. Did everything work as planned?

Comment: yes, it did, now they are all mounted at media i can access them, they just didn't appear in the left sidebar of nautilus, ultimately i wanted to achieve this by doing this whole thing 
 http://askubuntu.com/questions/900671/i-need-my-partitions-to-be-seen-in-sidebar-of-nautilus-but-not-in-places-menu-o

Comment: Well, just bookmark them by dragging them over to the side panel.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/900671/i-need-my-partitions-to-be-seen-in-sidebar-of-nautilus-but-not-in-places-menu-o  i did the same thing when they were mounted in /mnt but that created this problem